# First day of work as iOS Developer

Tags: job-offer, new-job

I just got an offer as an iOS developer and accepted. What should I expect on my first day on the job? Will I spend time setting up my environment and gaining access to their systems? I'm self-taught and this would be my first dev job outside of freelance work and not sure what to expect.

Comment: Pretty much what you said.  If its a large company you can also expect the first few hours sitting through HR stuff.  First days always suck.  Good luck.

Comment: It could also be that you sit around for the first two weeks, without computer any without anything to do ... or anything else. Nobody can give you a fortune telling. Just, don't panic, nothing of this sort is your fault.

Comment: This will most certainly vary from company to company and even across teams within the same company. Some companies get almost everything ready for you before your first day, others are more laid back and can take a couple of weeks to get things ready. It is usually a good idea to just go with the flow for the first week or so. Things will fall in place. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First Day?

> Here's where you sit/stand-up desk, and here's the bathroom, and here's the break room with microwave (with sign requesting people keep it clean) and fridge of other people's food. Team members, this is Anonymous. Anonymous, this is [name] and [name] and [name] and [face] and [name] and [face] and ...

//Waves awkwardly. Immediately forgets all names, job titles, and all but a few faces... Has to pee, knows where bathroom is. Success.

> and here's [paperwork] and [paperwork] and [workplace policy letters] and [paperwork].

//Clicks through PowerPoints on non-discrimination policy, sexual harassment awareness/prevention, cybersecurity, clocking work hours, etc.

//Checks box on paperwork promising not to watch porn in the office or on company time/equipment.

//How many exemptions on my W-4 again? Or, what's a W-4 again?

> Staff meeting, this is Anonymous, our new iOS dev; Anonymous, this is staff meeting. Anyway  [internal jargon], and [acronyms and internal jargon] and [quarterly project status] and [pie chart maybe] and [legacy system acronyms] and around the room, any questions? Ok...

//Wonders what to do for lunch.

//Goes to lunch with [name] and [name] and [face]. Remembers names now, probably.

... etc.

### After that?

First iOS dev job? Or first job?

If you've mostly done freelance front-end/iOS-only stuff all solo, expect to begin learning how to work in a team dev environment if you haven't before. Depending on the org, that could entail any number of new processes and approaches and tech you might not be used to.

Used Git? With other people? Used build servers and Continuous Integration & enterprise databases, etc? Used XCTest and a TDD approach?

Or, maybe you're *the* iOS person, but you also have to do Android, and full-stack development, and security? What are your responsibilities, and how do those match up against the gaps in your skill set? What's the plan to close the gaps?

Worked in the company's field/industry before? Had to deal with whatever relevant legal/statutory or fiduciary responsibilities before? Expect to spend time asking about & learning job processes and customer or legal requirements and business rules you'll be responsible for both following and implementing.

Depending on the organization, it could take hours, days, or weeks to get you set up with a work station, computer, accounts, etc. They probably won't give the untested brand new guy unfettered access to everything on the first day (would you?). They might give you a small side project to start, or they might throw you in with a team - depends on the org. Either way, they'll probably want to see what you can do w/o allowing you to do any serious damage.

Get clear expectations from your supervisor (if it's that kind of an org) or team. Ask lots of questions. Don't be a d-bag, and probably don't be the first person in the room to say the f-word. Might take a while to gauge the office culture, as with any job. Make friends, meet people, put yourself out there and have a good time.

Last suggestion is to ask what you want *all the rest* of your time there to be like. What do you want to learn or gain from this job & experience? Give some thought to what you hope to get out of this job as a developer, and then work towards those goals. That way even if it doesn't work out for whatever reason you still come out ahead.